# Reading Bitmaps from executable resources

Tags: c++, bitmap, allegro5

I'm making a game in allegro right now so i can teach myself about classes, object orientation and header files but i have some questions about the bitmaps and loading them

I can load bitmaps easily using:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = NULL;
image = al_load_bitmap("image.png");
```

But i want to import the png files in visual studio as resources (using resource.h and project.rc)

I've already checked this resource:

https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/604040/865263#target

and that code breaks my project horribly(messing up cmath and failing on the malloc functions)
and nothing else comes close to what i want.

Is there any way to load bitmaps from resources and if not whats the best way to integrate bitmaps into the executable so that i don't have to include a folder of pictures with my game?

They don't even have to be resources of the executable, i just don't want them to be user accessible, and i would prefer they be inside the executable but again its not important.

thanks for the help oh great wizards of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I started writing a content manager block for an Allegro5 project last year and never got around to finishing it. Essentially my idea for this problem was to load all my bitmaps up, gather the data you need (width, height, size of file), then write the resulting struct. For multiple files, you'd have to keep track of the offsets (file size) needed for each image written to seek appropriately, then reload in proper sequence. Relevant code for a single image, expand as needed:

Header:

```
struct IMAGE_DATA
{
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *file;
    int width;
    int height;
    int size;
};

class content_manager
{
private:
    ALLEGRO_FILE *content;
    char* bitmap_content_file_name;
    IMAGE_DATA test;

    void parse_image_file(IMAGE_DATA, char*);
public:
    content_manager(void);
    ~content_manager(void);
    void init_bitmap_content(void);
    void create_bitmap_content_file(void);  
};
```

Class:

```
content_manager::content_manager(void)
{
    bitmap_content_file_name = "data.arbitraryextension";
}


content_manager::~content_manager(void)
{
}

void content_manager::init_bitmap_content(void)
{
    content = al_fopen(bitmap_content_file_name, "rb");
    al_fread(content, test.file, test.size);
}

void content_manager::create_bitmap_content_file(void)
{
    parse_image_file(test, "images/image.png");
    content = al_fopen(bitmap_content_file_name, "wb");
    al_fwrite(content, test.file, test.size);
    al_fclose(content);
}

void content_manager::parse_image_file(IMAGE_DATA data, char* path)
{
    data.file = al_load_bitmap(path);
    data.size = sizeof(data.file);
    data.width = al_get_bitmap_width(data.file);
    data.height = al_get_bitmap_height(data.file);
}
```

create_bitmap_content_file would be expanded to include all the bitmaps you wanted to package up, then you would just include the data files you generated in your application deployment.

Comment: cursory glances make this look really difficult
however actually reading through the code make this super helpful